# Convert javascript number to float (single precision IEEE-754) and receive integer bits

Tags: javascript, ieee-754

I want to truncate a javascript number to single precision (float) and receive the integer bits. How can I do this?

For example: "5" is `0x40a00000` in IEEE-754 @ 32 bit. I want to do the 5 => `0x40a00000` mapping in Javascript.

Comment: I know there are quite a few IEEE-754 related questions out there but I wanted to share my knowledge in this Q&A thread. There was no other question that really fit my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution needs ES2015 to work and works in modern browsers and NodeJS.

Javascript numbers are doubles (IEEE-754 @ 64bit / double precision). With `Float32Array` we can truncate a f64 (double) value into a f32 (float) representation. With `Uint32Array` we can extract the raw integer bits afterwards.

Code on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/phip1611/u5b4ozks/19/

And as a Stack Snippet:

```js
// double is "number" (javascript data type)
function jsF64ToF32IntegerBitsStr(double) {
  // float / f32 has 32 bit => 4 bytes
  const BYTES = 4;
  // Buffer is like a raw view into memory
  const buffer = new ArrayBuffer(BYTES);
  // Float32Array: interpret bytes in the memory as f32 (IEEE-754) bits
  const float32Arr = new Float32Array(buffer);
  // UInt32Array: interpret bytes in the memory as unsigned integer bits.
  // Important that we use unsigned here, otherwise the MSB would be interpreted as sign
  const uint32Array = new Uint32Array(buffer);
  // will convert double to float during assignment
  float32Arr[0] = double;
  // now read the same memory as unsigned integer value
  const integerValue = uint32Array[0];
  // to hex string
  const integerBitsHex = integerValue.toString(16);
  // + hex prefix
  return '0x' + integerBitsHex;
}

// '0x40a00000'
console.log('5 in IEEE-754 single precision is: ', jsF64ToF32IntegerBitsStr(5));
// '0xc0490625'
console.log('-3.141 in IEEE-754 single precision is: ', jsF64ToF32IntegerBitsStr(-3.141));
// '0x7fffffff'
console.log('NaN in IEEE-754 single precision is: ', jsF64ToF32IntegerBitsStr(NaN));
```

You can verify the output against this neat online tool: https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html

Comment: Actually, since it was just a copy-and-paste, I've done the Stack Snippet for you.

Comment: Thanks! TBH I didn't know how the embedded snippet functionality works.

Comment: You're welcome! I've covered that in detail [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/) (for next time).

Comment: Though copying code from offsite as an edit is a copyright problem as per here: [Edits that add OP's code from 3rd party site where the license is unavailable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348698/edits-that-add-ops-code-from-3rd-party-site-where-the-license-is-unavailable)